# not able to switch icon in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle content with icon,icon is changing when i click for plus sign but it is not changing for minus again.basically i want to add plus sign for all the panel which are not open.
here is js:

```js
$(".toggle").click(function(e) {   
  $( this ).find('span').toggleClass( "accordion_icon_close accordion_icon_open" );     
   var $next=$(this).next().toggle(400);   
   $('.answer').not($next).hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle " profile='1' id="plus">Toggle <span class="accordion_icon_open"></span></div>
<div class="answer" rel='profile_1'>Answer</div>

<div class="toggle" profile='2'>Toggle <span class="accordion_icon_open"></span></div>
<div class="answer" rel='profile_2'>Answer</div>
```

Comment: $( this ).find('span').toggleClass( "accordion_icon_close, accordion_icon_open" ); Try to put comma in between two classes

Comment: What library does `accordion_icon_open` comes from, because your code works fine

Comment: @McBern there is no need for a `,` comma in the toggleClass

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ more info

Comment: Can you provide more info as to the actual problem you're having?  The code works fine, but does not show an icon in the snippet (as it's missing the class) but otherwise works fine.

Comment: Can you confirm your icons are working correctly without any code `<span class="accordion_icon_open"></span>` and `<span class="accordion_icon_close"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer, I use `fa` icons, since I don't have your icon set. and just add the class you want to replace inside `toggleClass()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("fa-minus");
    var next = $(this).next().toggle(400);
     $('.answer').not(next).hide(400);
     $('.toggle').not(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass("fa-plus");
  });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
 <div class="toggle " profile='1' id="plus">Toggle <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  </div>
 <div class="answer" rel='profile_1'>Answer</div>
<div>
<div class="container">
<div class="toggle" profile='2'>Toggle <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
<div class="answer" rel='profile_2'>Answer</div>
<div>
```

Comment: yes it is working fine when i click <div class="toggle" profile='1'>Toggle <span class="accordion_icon_open"></span></div>.it change its icon to - & if i again click on the same it collapse with + icon,its absolutely correct. But if i click on <div class="toggle" profile='1'>Toggle <span class="accordion_icon_open"></span></div> & then on <div class="toggle" profile='2'>Toggle <span class="accordion_icon_open"></span></div>.It does not change profile 1 icon to +...that is the only issue.otherwise it is working fine. I need help after $('.answer').not($next).hide(); Thanks –

Comment: @SudhaKushwaha check my answer again. I hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: if this is correct make sure to mark it as answer and give a vote.

Comment: Yes! it is working as expected.Thanks SilentCoder for great help.